# Avalonia UI - How to get/set properties of UI controls from code

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui

I have several `TabControl`s defined in my XAML. I would like my ViewModel to be aware of the `TabItem` name or the index of the `TabItem` that is selected.

I also have a `ScrollViewer` that i would like to always scroll to the bottom when ever a button is pressed.

I should be able to solve both of the above issues if i could somehow get access to the elements in my code.

How can i acheve something like this:

```
var tabIndex = this.GetElement<TabControl>("NameOfSomeTabControl").SelectedIndex;

var scrollViewer = this.GetElement<ScrollViewer>("NameOfSomeScrollViewer");
scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarValue = scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarMaximum;
```

Edit: [code for xaml](https://github.com/thezaza101/sc_ANN/blob/master/ui/Views/MainWindow.xaml), [viewModel code](https://github.com/thezaza101/sc_ANN/blob/master/ui/ViewModels/MainWindowViewModel.cs)

Edit 2:
Looks like i am able to get the instance of the element from the [window class](https://github.com/thezaza101/sc_ANN/blob/master/ui/Views/MainWindow.xaml.cs), however i'm still not sure how to pass the reference to the ViewModel.

Edit 3: I can achieve the scroll viewer going to the bottom automatically using the code below. however, once that method is invoked it seems like the scrolling gets disabled.

```
var tbRaw = this.Get<TextBlock>("tbRawOutput");
tbRaw.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => {
    var svRaw = this.Get<ScrollViewer>("svRawOutput");
    svRaw.Offset = new Vector(svRaw.Offset.X, svRaw.Extent.Height -svRaw.Viewport.Height);};
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this might be to use the `DataContextChanged` event handler in your main `Window` class:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContextChanged += (object sender, EventArgs wat) =>
    {
        // here, this.DataContext will be your MainWindowViewModel
    };
}
```

Then you can attach more event handlers/use getters and setters on the view model from the `Window`